# Four side by side figures each pair have one common caption

Tags: tables

I am using the following LaTeX code to put four figures in two rows with two figures side by side so that both of them are on a line and have a one common caption. Unfortunately when I am using the caption the LaTeX file does not execute properly. How can I do the above procedure? There is other code that does not work. I am using MiKTeX 2.8 and TeXnicCenter stable 2.3.

Here is my code:

```
\begin{figure}[htp]

\begin{tabular}{cc}

% Requires \usepackage{graphicx}
\includegraphics[width=13cm]{fig1.eps}&

\hspace{-5cm} \includegraphics[width=13cm]{fig2}\caption{}\

\includegraphics[width=13cm]{fig3.eps}& \hspace{-5cm} \includegraphics[width=13cm]{fig4.eps}\caption{}\
\end{tabular} \end{figure}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
SECOND CODE IS
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\includegraphics{fig1} &
\includegraphics{fig2}
\end{tabular}
\caption{.....}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\includegraphics{fig3} &
\includegraphics{fig4}
\end{tabular}
\caption{.....}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Why does your `SECOND CODE` not work?

Answer (score 2):

One option:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.4\linewidth]{fig2}\quad
  \includegraphics[width=.4\linewidth]{fig3}\par
  \caption{the caption for the first group}\par\bigskip
  \label{fig:testa}
  \includegraphics[width=.4\linewidth]{fig4}\quad
  \includegraphics[width=.4\linewidth]{fig4}
  \caption{the caption for the second group}
  \label{fig:testb}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Your settings for the width (`13cm`) were perhaps too wide for a standard document; it's better to control the width using a fraction of `\linewidth`, as I did in my example code.

The `demo` option for `graphicx` simply replaces actual figures with black rectangles; do *not* use that option in your actual document.